# How to update page asynchronously

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="input" size="20" class="FormText" readonly />
                <td />
                <tr />
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" name="one" value="1">
                <td />
                <tr />
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want when button 1 is pressed to show 1 in the input field on the same page. I know this is achieved by Ajax but I cant make it. I read lot of articles but nothing helps.

Comment: This isn't a case to use AJAX. This seems more like an onclick event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` to do so. Have a look as follows:

```
function addValue(value) {
 document.form.input.value=value;
}
```

You have to set this `javascript` source code in a `javascript` section (it is placed usually at the head code).

In order to invoke that code, you should tell 'button' where the function is defined:

```
<input type="button" name="one" value="1" onClick='addValue(1)'>
```

And that's all.

Comment: why u put addValue(1) in single quotes but put "one" or "1" in double?

Comment: It does not matter at all. HTML 4 or 5 assumes single or double quotes in the same way. To be more accuracy, it should be written in double quotes.